# Help with loose faucet, bottom part is secure

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have an issue with a loose faucet. It appears the threads at the base are not connecting properly to the threads in the upper "tube" (sorry, not sure the technical term). The faucet is rocking around during use and I can essentially life the faucet straight off the base with just a small bit of force and wiggling as the picture illustrates. I cannot get much "bite" at all when I try to screw it into the base.

The base is very secure. The plumber had issues because the previous owner made the counter hole too big. So the base is epoxied to the counter very securely, and the bolts underneath are all tight. The issue is with this upper construction.

Is this something where I could put epoxy on those bottom threads and glue the whole thing together? This is a stopgap for a full remodel maybe 1-2 years in the future where we'll replace out the whole countertop.

[image: loose faucet]

Comment: The threads are probably damaged, what is called stripped.  Any glue should hold, but any removal will probably require it to come out in pieces.  If that piece is required to be remove for repairs/fix leaks, might want to think about using small screws to hold it in.  Use pilot holes(drill small holes for screws to go in).  Looks like the water hose/pipe is separate to the bottom housing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epoxy... well you can try, but if there is a leak, or you remodel in the future, you will be cursing at the guy that did it.

You should not screw on upper part without disconnecting the water hose under the counter. (but you know that already).

I would recommend using pins inserts from the side. It looks like you have access to insert 3 pins.

[image: pins]

Screw on upper part and drill holes for the pins. Since the valve body is very close to the counter you might not be able to drill perfectly horizontal. That does not matter, actually it helps from keeping the pins falling out, since you will drill slightly angled.

Drill all the way true the inner metal part but not in the water hose.

If you use pins with head, they will not fall through